# how to make transition animation when changing photos in Flex

Tags: apache-flex, actionscript-3

I have an image  in Flex I want to change the image with actionscript to show some other image say every 3 seconds or so. I also want to make transition between the image and the next one for instance fade in/out. What is the best way to do so?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to fade in the new image while at the same time fading out the old, use a Parallel object:

```
var p:Parallel = new Parallel();
var fadeOut:Fade = new Fade(image1);
fadeOut.alphaFrom = 1;
fadeOut.alphaTo = 0;
var fadeIn:Fade = new Fade(image2);
fadeIn.alphaFrom = 0;
fadeIn.alphaTo = 1;
p.addChild(fadeOut);
p.addChild(fadeIn);
p.duration = 1000; //time in ms
p.play();
```

Answer (score 1):

Picking things up when you already have an image up:

Use the [**Fade**](http://livedocs.adobe.com/flex/3/langref/mx/effects/Fade.html) effect on the first image. Make its alphaFrom="1.0" and its alphaTo="0.0". It willthen dispatch an `EffectEnd` event. In your handler for that event, switch the target image source and call another `Fade` effect, that switches the alphaFrom and alphaTo values and switches the image source. Then just use a timer or setTimeout (or setInterval) to stay on the image a certain length of time, then rinse and repeat. Look at the example in the link provided above. It's really not hard.

Answer (score 1):

Use a timer to change the [image source](http://livedocs.adobe.com/flex/3/langref/mx/controls/SWFLoader.html#source) attribute in conjunction with [Fade](http://livedocs.adobe.com/flex/3/langref/mx/effects/Fade.html) Effects.

The general gist is:

1. Timer Ends
2. Start Fade Out Effect
3. On Fade Out Effect complete, change image source
4. Start Fade In Effect
5. On Fade in Complete, restart timer